# Why am I getting the error "The project target is not set"

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

![enter image description here][1]

i tried to set it manually in java build path -> libraries 
But i dint find anything as Android x.y versions. have a look at ma screen shot and please suggest me..!
In main.xml I'm getting the error as "The project target is not set"
But in manifest I did all the changes but still the error sustains.
If I need to install ADT  plugin i cant able to it as Help->Check for updates is not working properly

Comment: Screenshot missing ... paste the link here and someone with sufficient rep will be able to edit the question to include it for you

Comment: Please, post your AndroidManifest.xml and your project.properties as well as a link to a site (even your dropbox page) where we can see the screenshot. If you could post your LogCat, too, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your Manifest if they are not already there:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="[number of the API level you wish to use]" />
```

You can also add a minimum SDK version, detailing which is the minimum API level that your app is compatible with.  For example:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```